# How does Pyarrow read_csv handle different file encodings?

Tags: csv, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a .dat file that I had been reading with `pd.read_csv` and always needed to use `encoding="latin"` for it to read properly / without error.  When I use `pyarrow.csv.read_csv` I dont see a parameter to select the encoding of the file but it still works without issue(which is great! but i dont understand why / if it only auto handles certain encodings).  The only parameters im using are setting the `delimiter="|"` (with ParseOptions) and `auto_dict_encode=True` with (ConvertOptions).

How is pyarrow handling different encoding types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyarrow` currently has no functionality to deal with different encodings, and assumes UTF8 for string/text data.
But the reason it doesn't raise an error is that pyarrow will read any non-UTF8 strings as a "binary" type column, instead of "string" type.

A small example:

```py
# writing a small file with latin encoding 
with open("test.csv", "w", encoding="latin") as f: 
    f.writelines(["col1,col2\n", "u,ù"])
```

Reading with pyarrow gives string for the first column (which only contains ASCII characters, thus also valid UTF8), but reads the second column as binary:

```py
>>> from pyarrow import csv 
>>> csv.read_csv("test.csv")
pyarrow.Table
col1: string
col2: binary
```

With pandas you indeed get an error by default (because pandas has no binary data type, and will try to read all text columns as python strings, thus UTF8):

```py
>>> pd.read_csv("test.csv")
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte

>>> pd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding="latin")

  col1 col2
0    u    ù
```

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to specify encodings with pyarrow.read_csv.
According to the pyarrow [docs for read_csv](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html#character-encoding):

> The encoding can be changed using the [ReadOptions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.ReadOptions.html) class.

A minimal example follows:

```py
from pyarrow import csv

options = csv.ReadOptions(encoding='latin1')
table = csv.read_csv('path/to/file', options)
```

From what I can tell, the functionality was added in [this PR](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/7456), so it should work starting with pyarrow 1.0.